# Growl Python binding with Click feedback?

Tags: python, macos, pyobjc, growl

I'm trying to use the Growl Python bindings (Growl.py v0.7 from the Growl repository) to write a small application. One of the features that's currently missing is the click notification sent to Python.

I know in Objective-C, when a user clicks the notification, it will send a trigger to the running application. I'd like to do a similar thing with the Python bindings. When a user clicks a notification, I'd like to have the Python program open a URL in the browser (or handle the event in another manner).

Any thoughts on how I might accomplish it?

**Update:** thanks to synthesizerpatel who provides a promising solution and I take his words it worked on Lion. Unfortunately, I'm beginning to fade out from Mac, so I don't do much Mac programming anymore. Though, I did some debugging as it's still not working on Snow Leopard, and here is why:

[Discussion Growl PyObjC not working with PyObjC 2.2b3](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/growldiscuss/zNhgExOsE-w)

[Source code](https://github.com/SPlyer/MacTimeLog/commit/ffc74ce3a03300e263b334ebd613999c78f17474)

Comment: Any luck here? I'd love to know as well.

Comment: Are you looking for this to catch all growl notifications or just a python app that has the ability to send growl notifications and for it to be able to catch the mouse click when the user dismisses it?

Comment: Mainly just python application.

Comment: For what it's worth (to whoever else might be interested in this problem/solution, Lion's objc.__version__ reports **2.3.2a0**. It might be possible to build the objc stuff from their SVN for Snow Leopard. But, in a nutshell the objc module is a great idea, but just lacks a vibrant development community as far as I can tell. I'm happy it's working on Lion, but if you look through their source tree you can see over time how many of the examples have been removed because they stopped working at some point and nobody bothered to fix them. **caveat pyobjc**.

Comment: Yes, I can probably recompile pyobjc and it will work on my machine. Though, it's not feasible to ask every end user to reinstall pyobjc in order to just use my app. Thus, another approach should be taken... I do like pyobjc idea, but

Comment: Like @synthesizerpatel said, a lot of development has moved away from pyobjc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
#
# pyGrr!
#
# This code was originally found @
# http://www.cocoaforge.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=13359&p=91992&hilit=pyobjc+growl
# It is (to the best of our knowledge) the work of user 'tooru' on the same
# website.
#
# I make no claim to this code, all I did was get it working with PyObjC on Lion
# reformatted it a bit and added some more verbose explanations of what the script
# does. To be honest, I haven't touched pyobjc in a couple years and I was amazed
# that it still works! Even more amazed that I was able to get this example working
# in about 20 minutes.
#
# Great job tooru! 
# 
#   I have verified this code works with the following combination of 
#   packages / versions
#
#   * OSX Lion 10.7.3
#   * Python 2.7
#   * Growl 1.3
#   * Growl SDK 1.3.1
#
# 
# - Nathan Ramella nar@hush.com (http://www.remix.net)
##################################################################################

import objc
from Foundation import *
from AppKit import *
from PyObjCTools import AppHelper
import time
import sys
import os

myGrowlBundle = objc.loadBundle(
  "GrowlApplicationBridge",
  globals(),
  bundle_path = objc.pathForFramework(
    '/Library/Frameworks/Growl.framework'
  )
)

class MenuMakerDelegate(NSObject):

  """
  This is a delegate for Growl, a required element of using the Growl
  service.

  There isn't a requirement that delegates actually 'do' anything, but
  in this case, it does. We'll make a little menu up on the status bar
  which will be named 'pyGrr!'

  Inside the menu will be two options, 'Send a Grr!', and 'Quit'. 

  Send a Grr! will emit a growl notification that when clicked calls back
  to the Python code so you can take some sort of action - if you're that
  type of person.
  """

  statusbar = None
  state = 'idle'

  def applicationDidFinishLaunching_(self, notification):

    """
    Setup the menu and our menu items. Getting excited yet?
    """

    statusbar = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar()
    # Create the statusbar item
    self.statusitem = statusbar.statusItemWithLength_(NSVariableStatusItemLength)

    self.statusitem.setHighlightMode_(1)  # Let it highlight upon clicking
    self.statusitem.setToolTip_('pyGrr!')   # Set a tooltip
    self.statusitem.setTitle_('pyGrr!')   # Set an initial title

    # Build a very simple menu
    self.menu = NSMenu.alloc().init()
    menuitem = NSMenuItem.alloc().initWithTitle_action_keyEquivalent_(
      'Send a Grr!',
      'rcNotification:',
      ''
    )
    self.menu.addItem_(menuitem)

    # Default event
    menuitem = NSMenuItem.alloc().initWithTitle_action_keyEquivalent_(
      'Quit',
      'terminate:',
      ''
    )
    self.menu.addItem_(menuitem)

    # Bind it to the status item
    self.statusitem.setMenu_(self.menu)

  def rcNotification_(self,notification):

    """
    This is run when you select the 'Send a Grr!' menu item. It 
    will lovingly bundle up a Grr and send it Growl's way.
    """

    print "Sending a growl notification at", time.time()

    GrowlApplicationBridge.notifyWithTitle_description_notificationName_iconData_priority_isSticky_clickContext_(
      "Grr! - I'm a title!",
      "This is where you put notification information.",
      "test1",
      None,
      0,
      False,
      "this ends up being the argument to your context callback"
    )

class rcGrowl(NSObject):

  """
  rcGrowl registers us with Growl to send out Grrs on behalf
  of the user and do 'something' with the results when a 
  Grr has been clicked.

  For additional information on what the what is going on
  please refer to the growl dox @ 

  http://growl.info/documentation/developer/implementing-growl.php
  """

  def rcSetDelegate(self):
    GrowlApplicationBridge.setGrowlDelegate_(self)

  def registrationDictionaryForGrowl(self):

    """
    http://growl.info/documentation/developer/implementing-growl.php#registration
    """

    return {
      u'ApplicationName'    :   'rcGrowlMacTidy',
      u'AllNotifications'   :   ['test1'],
      u'DefaultNotifications' :   ['test1'],
      u'NotificationIcon'   :   None,
    } 

  # don't know if it is working or not
  def applicationNameForGrowl(self):
    """ 
    Identifies the application.
    """
    return 'rcGrowlMacTidy'

  #def applicationIconDataForGrowl(self):
    """
    If you wish to include a custom icon with the Grr,
    you can do so here. Disabled by default since I didn't
    want to bloat up this up
    """
    #icon = NSImage.alloc().init()
    #icon = icon.initWithContentsOfFile_(u'remix_icon.tiff')
    #return icon

  def growlNotificationWasClicked_(self, ctx):

    """
    callback for onClick event
    """
    print "we got a click! " + str(time.time()) + " >>> " + str(ctx) + " <<<\n"

  def growlNotificationTimedOut_(self, ctx):

    """ 
    callback for timing out
    """
    print "We timed out" + str(ctx) + "\n"

  def growlIsReady(self):

    """
    Informs the delegate that GrowlHelperApp was launched
    successfully. Presumably if it's already running it
    won't need to run it again?
    """
    print "growl IS READY"


if __name__ == "__main__":

  # Both 'growlnotify' and this script seem to have the following
  # error after emitting a Grr!
  #
  # Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=4 "Read operation timed out" 
  # UserInfo=0x7fa444e00070 {NSLocalizedDescription=Read operation timed out}
  # 
  # So, we redirect stderr to /dev/null so that it doesn't muck up
  # the output of this script. Some folks say upgrading Growl fixes it,
  # others still have the problem. Doesn't seem to make much of a difference
  # one way or another, things still seem to work regardless.

  fp = os.open('/dev/null', os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREAT, 0o666)
  dupped = os.dup(2)
  os.dup2(fp, 2)

  # set up system statusbar GUI
  app = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
  delegate = MenuMakerDelegate.alloc().init()
  app.setDelegate_( delegate )

  # set up growl delegate
  rcGrowlDelegate=rcGrowl.new()
  rcGrowlDelegate.rcSetDelegate()
  AppHelper.runEventLoop()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the script. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me as I have snow leopard with growl 1.2.2

Comment: If anything you should have less problems in that case. :D But, as it is, this is exactly what you're looking for. I'd be curious to hear what error messages you're getting.

Comment: Yeah, I should have provided more detail... The script did sound promising as what I want. After I ran the program, it created the status menu with two options. Though, after I clicked "Send a Grr!", I only got a message in console with "Sending a growl notification at ..." without actual Growl notification.

Comment: In other words, the Growl notification never showed up, and I checked the system preference, the pyGrr! app didn't seem to be registered either. I wonder if there is API change from 1.2.2 -> 1.3

Comment: I think I know whats going on - right after the 'if __name__ == '__main__', remove the 3 lines of code that redirect stderr to /dev/null. You might get a better error message. It looks like there were API changes between 1.2.1 and 1.3.. And since I only have Lion I can't really give you any insight. You should upgrade to Lion already anyway. :D

Comment: Another thing that occurred to me - since the effort I put into that script was to _update_ it to work on Lion with new-growl, you might be able to just use the original which is circa (2007..) - it might 'just work' for you. Check the comments in the header of what I posted and you can find it there.

Comment: By the way, I found the incompatibility between your script and growl 1.2.2. It's the notification icon. If you comment out the notification icon dictionary item, the script wont complaint though still no notification. Just fyi